# Iterate (loop) at user level in PySpark dataframe DF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Imagine I have the following DF in PySpark where UB and LB stand for Upper Bound and Lower Bound, respectively.

```
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+
| user_id | row | currentValue |  UB  |  LB  |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+
| usr001  |   1 |           12 | 7.2  | 16.8 |
| usr001  |   2 |           20 | 12   | 28   |
| usr001  |   3 |           17 | 10.2 | 23.8 |
| usr001  |   4 |           21 | 12.6 | 29.4 |
| usr001  |   5 |            9 | 5.4  | 12.6 |
| usr001  |   6 |           23 | 13.8 | 32.2 |
| usr002  |   1 |           11 | 6.6  | 15.4 |
| usr002  |   2 |           10 | 6    | 14   |
| usr002  |   3 |           15 | 9    | 21   |
| usr002  |   4 |            3 | 1.8  | 4.2  |
| usr002  |   5 |            4 | 2.4  | 5.6  |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+
```

For each user in DF, I'd like to apply some logic/rules so that currentValue can be updated to updatedValue. Logic/rules as follows:

user_id: usr001

1. For row 1: currentValue = updatedValue (for all users)
2. For row 2: if currentValue is within LB and UB in row 1 (if 20 is between 7.2 and 16.8) then updatedValue in row 2 equals currentValue in row 1 (updatedValue in row 2 = 12). Else, updatedValue = currentValue (updatedValue = 20)
3. Because in row 2, updatedValue = currentValue, row 3 compares to row 2.
   For row 3: if currentValue is within LB and UB in row 2 (if 17 is between 12 and 28) then updatedValue in row 3 equals currentValue in row 2 (updatedValue in row 3 = 20). Else, updatedValue = currentValue (updatedValue = 17)
4. Because in row 3, updatedValue in row 3 = currentValue in row 2, row 4 compares to row 2.
   For row 4: if currentValue is within LB and UB in row 2 (if 21 is between 12 and 28) then updatedValue in row 4 equals currentValue in row 2 (updatedValue in row 4 = 20). Else, updatedValue = currentValue (updatedValue = 21)
5. Because in row 4, updatedValue in row 4 = currentValue in row 2, row 5 compares to row 2.
   For row 5: if currentValue is within LB and UB in row 2 (if 9 is between 12 and 28) then updatedValue in row 5 equals currentValue in row 2 (updatedValue in row 5 = 20). Else, updatedValue = currentValue (updatedValue = 9)
6. Because in row 5, updatedValue = currentValue, row 6 compares to row 5.
   For row 6: if currentValue is within LB and UB in row 5 (if 23 is between 5.4 and 12.6) then updatedValue in row 6 equals currentValue in row 2 (updatedValue in row 5 = 20). Else, updatedValue = currentValue (updatedValue = 9)

Exact rules will apply for usr002. The expected output is as follows:

```
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+--------------+
| user_id | row | currentValue |  UB  |  LB  | updatedValue |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+--------------+
| usr001  |   1 |           12 | 7.2  | 16.8 |           12 |
| usr001  |   2 |           20 | 12   | 28   |           20 |
| usr001  |   3 |           17 | 10.2 | 23.8 |           20 |
| usr001  |   4 |           21 | 12.6 | 29.4 |           20 |
| usr001  |   5 |            9 | 5.4  | 12.6 |            9 |
| usr001  |   6 |           23 | 13.8 | 32.2 |           23 |
| usr002  |   1 |           11 | 6.6  | 15.4 |           11 |
| usr002  |   2 |           10 | 6    | 14   |           11 |
| usr002  |   3 |           15 | 9    | 21   |           11 |
| usr002  |   4 |            3 | 1.8  | 4.2  |            3 |
| usr002  |   5 |            4 | 2.4  | 5.6  |            3 |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+------+--------------+
```

Is there a way this can be implemented in Spark? I appreciate any help!

`Spark: 2.4.4`

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Is it possible that your example contains a wrong updatedValue ? If I follow your logic  I would think that the updateValue of row "| usr002  |3 |15 | 9| 21|11 |" should be 15

Comment: @RudyVerboven, why it should 15? as per his logic for user "usr002" , rowid # 2 's updated value is equal to rowid#1 so for rowid#3 it will check range og rowid#1 not #2. so rowid#3's current value (15) is in range of rowid#1 which is 6.6 to 15.4 since it is in range so its update value will be rowid #1 current value

Comment: I'm sorry you'r right. You probably can achieve the result with using some window magic. ex. Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("row").rowsBetween(-1, -1)

Comment: @RudyVerboven -- tried python already but it won't scale (i.e. distribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions. But its not that simple. Here is step by step explanation of code and logic.

(in below codes and explanation uv and updatedValue are not the same)

1.Read df

```
df=spark.read.csv(path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

2.Specify the window

```
w=Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("row")
```

3.Create a column which compares current value with just UB and LB of previous row, if its in range then return previous row currentValue else return the same row currentValue, lets call this column "uv"

```
df2=df.withColumn("uv",when(col("row")==1,col("currentValue"))
.when(col("currentValue").between(lag("UB",1).over(w),                                          
lag("LB",1).over(w)),lag("currentValue",1).over(w))
.otherwise(col("currentValue"))).orderBy("user_id")
```

df2:

```
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+
|user_id|row|currentValue|  UB|  LB| uv|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+
| usr001|  1|          12| 7.2|16.8| 12|
| usr001|  2|          20|12.0|28.0| 20|
| usr001|  3|          17|10.2|23.8| 20|
| usr001|  4|          21|12.6|29.4| 17|
| usr001|  5|           9| 5.4|12.6|  9|
| usr001|  6|          23|13.8|32.2| 23|
| usr002|  1|          11| 6.6|15.4| 11|
| usr002|  2|          10| 6.0|14.0| 11|
| usr002|  3|          15| 9.0|21.0| 15|
| usr002|  4|           3| 1.8| 4.2|  3|
| usr002|  5|           4| 2.4| 5.6|  3|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+
```

4.This is the main logic, as per your logic for row 5(usr001) first we have to check if row 4 updatedValue is filled with row4 currentValue, if its filled then compare row 5 value with row 4 bounds,else we have to goto row from which row 4 updatedValue is filled and compare with those bounds, to implement this in the above step mark all values where currentValue==uv.

```
df3=df2.withColumn("comp_row", when(col("currentValue")==col("uv"), col("row")))
```

df3:

```
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
|user_id|row|currentValue|  UB|  LB| uv|comp_row|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
| usr001|  1|          12| 7.2|16.8| 12|       1|
| usr001|  2|          20|12.0|28.0| 20|       2|
| usr001|  3|          17|10.2|23.8| 20|    null|
| usr001|  4|          21|12.6|29.4| 17|    null|
| usr001|  5|           9| 5.4|12.6|  9|       5|
| usr001|  6|          23|13.8|32.2| 23|       6|
| usr002|  1|          11| 6.6|15.4| 11|       1|
| usr002|  2|          10| 6.0|14.0| 11|    null|
| usr002|  3|          15| 9.0|21.0| 15|       3|
| usr002|  4|           3| 1.8| 4.2|  3|       4|
| usr002|  5|           4| 2.4| 5.6|  3|    null|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
```

5.Now if we back fill the nulls of each row, we get the row number against which each row should compare to.

```
df4 = df3.withColumn("comp_row",last("comp_row",True).over(w))
```

df4:

```
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
|user_id|row|currentValue|  UB|  LB| uv|comp_row|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
| usr001|  1|          12| 7.2|16.8| 12|       1|
| usr001|  2|          20|12.0|28.0| 20|       2|
| usr001|  3|          17|10.2|23.8| 20|       2|
| usr001|  4|          21|12.6|29.4| 17|       2|
| usr001|  5|           9| 5.4|12.6|  9|       5|
| usr001|  6|          23|13.8|32.2| 23|       6|
| usr002|  1|          11| 6.6|15.4| 11|       1|
| usr002|  2|          10| 6.0|14.0| 11|       1|
| usr002|  3|          15| 9.0|21.0| 15|       3|
| usr002|  4|           3| 1.8| 4.2|  3|       4|
| usr002|  5|           4| 2.4| 5.6|  3|       4|
+-------+---+------------+----+----+---+--------+
```

Note: values of comp_row indicates which row the next row should compare to, example: row 4(usr001) comp_row contains 2 it means row 5 compares to row 2.

6.Now that we know which row compares to which row all we need to do is just get the bounds of these rows. To do that we need to join row with comp_row, that way we can get the bounds of row 2 in row 4.

```
df5 = df4.select("user_id",col("row").alias("comp_row"),
col("UB").alias("new_UB"),col("LB").alias("new_LB")
,col("currentValue").alias("new_currentValue")) 
# Note: Here row is selected as comp_row.

df6=df5.join(df4,["user_id","comp_row"],"inner").orderBy("user_id","row")

df6.select("user_id",
"UB","LB"
,"new_UB","new_LB"
,"currentValue","new_currentValue"
,"row","comp_row").show()

+-------+----+----+------+------+------------+----------------+---+--------+
|user_id|  UB|  LB|new_UB|new_LB|currentValue|new_currentValue|row|comp_row|
+-------+----+----+------+------+------------+----------------+---+--------+
| usr001| 7.2|16.8|   7.2|  16.8|          12|              12|  1|       1|
| usr001|12.0|28.0|  12.0|  28.0|          20|              20|  2|       2|
| usr001|10.2|23.8|  12.0|  28.0|          17|              20|  3|       2|
| usr001|12.6|29.4|  12.0|  28.0|          21|              20|  4|       2|
| usr001| 5.4|12.6|   5.4|  12.6|           9|               9|  5|       5|
| usr001|13.8|32.2|  13.8|  32.2|          23|              23|  6|       6|
| usr002| 6.6|15.4|   6.6|  15.4|          11|              11|  1|       1|
| usr002| 6.0|14.0|   6.6|  15.4|          10|              11|  2|       1|
| usr002| 9.0|21.0|   9.0|  21.0|          15|              15|  3|       3|
| usr002| 1.8| 4.2|   1.8|   4.2|           3|               3|  4|       4|
| usr002| 2.4| 5.6|   1.8|   4.2|           4|               3|  5|       4|
+-------+----+----+------+------+------------+----------------+---+--------+
```

7.The final Step and Boom!!, Compare currentValues with new bounds in previous row if its within bounds then updatedValue=new_currentValue of previous row else updatedValue=currentValue of same row.

```
df7=df6.withColumn("updatedValue",when(col("row")==1,col("currentValue"))\
.when(col("currentValue").between(lag("new_UB",1).over(w),                                               
lag("new_LB",1).over(w)),lag("new_currentValue",1).over(w))             
.otherwise(col("currentValue"))).orderBy("user_id")\
.select("user_id","currentValue","UB","LB","updatedValue")
```

df7:

```
+-------+------------+----+----+------------+
|user_id|currentValue|  UB|  LB|updatedValue|
+-------+------------+----+----+------------+
| usr001|          12| 7.2|16.8|          12|
| usr001|          20|12.0|28.0|          20|
| usr001|          17|10.2|23.8|          20|
| usr001|          21|12.6|29.4|          20|
| usr001|           9| 5.4|12.6|           9|
| usr001|          23|13.8|32.2|          23|
| usr002|          11| 6.6|15.4|          11|
| usr002|          10| 6.0|14.0|          11|
| usr002|          15| 9.0|21.0|          11|
| usr002|           3| 1.8| 4.2|           3|
| usr002|           4| 2.4| 5.6|           3|
+-------+------------+----+----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! this is fantastic! you provided a couple of approaches that definitely helped me to extrapolate this to several millions users. Appreciate the time.

Comment: Great..glad I could help!